# ComponentArt grid control not working after upgrade to VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2005, ajaxcontroltoolkit, componentart

I'm not sure if someone on here will know a reason for this, but I always have good luck with this community.

I've recently taken over an old forgotten web site project that was running on .net 2.0 in VS 2005. After validating that it worked, I upgraded the project to VS 2010. The problem happening now is that the grid control, ComponentArt, is no longer rendering.

version 2008.2.1232.3

I have a post on the ComponentArt forums also, but it doesn't seem to get much traffic.

Is there anybody out there with any experience with this component? I've never used this, but other components have always been pretty straightforward to use in VS.

Could this be an incompatibility between the control and VS 2010?

---

**EDIT**: I believe this may be related somehow to the ajax control toolkit, but I'm not quite sure how. I noticed the `sys.webforms is undefined` javascript error so I added a scriptmanager to the page. Not sure how or why this would have worked in VS 2005 without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the clientIDMode in the web.config resolved the issue

```
<system.web>  
     <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

Answer (score 0):

When migrating a web project from VS2008 to VS2017 (.Net Framework 4.5) I found the error `'The data could not be loaded'` using ComponentArt:CallBack controls and I found that I needed to restore .Net Framework 3.5 behaviour setting not only `controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion` and `clientIDMode` but also:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

See [ASP.NET 4 Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) for more information.